# Vlook up between two google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have two google sheet workbooks. On the untitled Spreadsheet workbook I want the link that's on Colm B to appear from "links" workbook to appear on column I on the "untitled spreadsheet" when the trailer appears on column B.

I have this

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("I will put the http for the Link spreadsheet here ,"Sheet!!A1:B")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in I2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B; IMPORTRANGE("id"; "Sheet!!A:B"); 2; 0)))
```